# How to exit from 'while' statement when finding a '&nbsp;' in gridView asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have an uploaded excel file to my app. and need to stop reading cells when the first blank cell is found.

here is my code :

```
        //Start Counting Records
        int GIndex = 10;
        string Rowdata = null;
        while (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text))
        {
            Rowdata += GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text + "\n";
            GIndex++;
        }
```

also i tried to use this :

```
        //Start Counting Records
        int GIndex = 10;
        string Rowdata = null;
        while (GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text) != "&nbps;")
        {
            Rowdata += GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text + "\n";
            GIndex++;
        }
```

also :

```
        //Start Counting Records
        int GIndex = 10;
        string Rowdata = null;
        while(string.Compare(GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text,"&nbsp;")!=0)
        {
            Rowdata += GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text + "\n";
            GIndex++;
        }
```

so how can I detect blank spaces in gridview?

Comment: It sounds like you know that it is going past blank cells which suggests you know where the blank cells are. Can you not just stop in a debugger and see what the value of Text is at that point of if there is any other property on the cell that you can use as your condition?

Comment: What is the *actual value* of `GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text` when you encounter the problem?

Comment: I have this in debugger GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text = "&nbsp;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Trim` to see if you have a cell with empty value by using `string.IsNullOrEmpty`

```
while (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text.Trim()))
{
  Rowdata += GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text + "\n";
  GIndex++;
}
```

And if you receive the cell having text `&nbsp;` you can compare it by converting to `UppperCase` or `LowerCase`

```
while (GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text.Trim().ToUpperCase()) != "&NBSP;")
{
  Rowdata += GridView1.Rows[GIndex].Cells[1].Text + "\n";
  GIndex++;
}
```